# Spring JPA : Want to add key-value pair in json column

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mysql-json

I am using spring jpa(spring-data-jpa-1.11.4) with mysql connector-5.
In mysql, I have a table named chat_templates with column cta_data of json type.

**Use Case** :I want to add a new key-value pair in existing json of mysql column.

**Observations:** I have tried mysql native query on mysql cli which is working fine and i am able to add new key-value pair in json column.

> update chat_templates set cta_data=JSON_INSERT(**cta_data**,'$.**new_test_key**',**23232**)  where id=777;
>
> mysql> select cta_data from chat_templates where id =777\G;
> *************************** 1. row ***************************
> cta_data: {"?1": "jjjjjj", "dsd": 23232, "ioi": "jjjjjj", "klm": 1, "aaaa": "kkkkksds", "cta1": {"link": "paytmmp://fastag", "text": "Upload Documents"}, "cta2": null, "jjkjj": 11111, "rttrt": 577, "hhuugu": 11111, "klm111": 1, "nnnnnn": 11111, **"new_test_key": 23232**}
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)

But when i am using similar query on spring jpa. It is not working. Giving me error

> ```
> @Modifying
> @Transactional
> @Query(value = "update chat_templates c set c.cta_data = JSON_INSERT(c.cta_data, '$.?1', ?1)  where c.id=777", nativeQuery = true)
> void test(int  k);
> ```

Error logs :

> Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 4.

> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Then i have made some changes(removed single quotes) on query, still getting another type of error.

> ```
> @Modifying
> @Transactional
> @Query(value = "update chat_templates c set c.cta_data = JSON_INSERT(c.cta_data, $.?1, ?1)  where c.id=777", nativeQuery = true)
> void test(int  k);
> ```

Error logs :

> **Unknown column '$.**new_test_key**' in 'field list'**         (new_test_key is the dynamic value)

> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Kindly suggest if i have missed anything.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: $.?1 isn't going to work, as JPA will bind ?1 as a parameter to the statement. If you want to issue a query like this, you are going to need to build the query string dynamically yourself (String query = "update chat_templates c set c.cta_data = JSON_INSERT(c.cta_data, '$."+param+"', "+param+")  where c.id=777" )and issue it using the EntityManager.createNativeQuery(string) api

Comment: I suggest you use Gson.